# Time information of type DATETIME alternative with BIGINT or DOUBLE (Unix Time)

Tags: mysql, performance, datetime, mysql-5.5

Let's say I'm stuck with `mysql 5.5` and I'm not able to change to `5.6` or `5.7`, therefore I'm not able to use `DATETIME` with fractional seconds, which is information that I need. I would like to know what is the best solution. One of the alternatives that I've been thinking is to use `BIGINT` to save information with the form of the bash command `date +%s%N` (unix time) or `DOUBLE` if I want to separate seconds and fractions of seconds (i.e. `date +%s.%N`).

What would be the drawbacks of such configuration? Besides not using standard format.

Answer (score 1):

You can use BIGINT to store Unix time in milliseconds (Javascript timestamps).

Or, either of your other solutions (fractional-second time in `DOUBLE` or unix time in `BIGINT`) will work.

The important thing for a table of any size is the ability to index the column.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Then, do you know any drawback? Or what is the deal with timestamp and datetime, that it is standard format and you can search in standard date-time format, right?

Answer (score 1):

- Any use of any datetime function would need to be modified in some way.  This should not be a big deal, just more code for you to write for inputting and displaying.
- `BIGINT` is 8 bytes.  This leads to more disk space; probably not a serious problem.
- No issue with `WHERE` clauses, range tests, `ORDER BY`, etc.; `DATETIME`, `TIMESTAMP`, `BIGINT`, `DOUBLE` all allow all variations.
- Any performance differences are insignificant.  But be sure to not "hide an indexed column in a function call".

Java users do it (milliseconds in a `BIGINT`) all the time.

Comment: Thanks for the insights! =). I actually don't need to modify that much the dates once I have them that way, I will do mainly operation of differences in seconds between the added rows (that's why I was wondering if there was no problem with `BIGINT` or `DOUBLE` to represent the date).